more free variables in  normal forms
If $x, v_1, ..., v_i$ are variables and $t_1, ..., t_j$ are $\lambda$-terms, and $s$ is the $\beta \eta$-normal form of $$\lambda v_1 ... \lambda v_i (x t_1 ... t_j)$$
then must $x$ occur free in $s$?

Is $v_i \neq x$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$?

It depends on whether there is $1 \leq n \leq i$ such that $v_n = x$ or not.
Indeed, since $x$ occurs in head position in $\lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_i.xt_1 \dots t_j$, it cannot be discarded via $\beta\eta$-reduction, hence it will still occur in head position in $s$.
Therefore, either $x = v_n$ for some $1 \leq n \leq i$ and then $x$ cannot occur free in $s$ because $\lambda v_n$ is also present in $s$, or $x \neq v_n$ for all $1 \leq n \leq i$ and then $x$ still occurs free in head position in $s$.

Actually, to be more rigorous and more informative in the answer, we can use a crucial property of the $\lambda$-calculus called postponement of $\eta$ after $\beta$: if a term $\beta\eta$-reduces to another one then it can reach that term by first performing $\beta$-steps and then performing $\eta$-steps, that is, if $t \to_{\beta\eta}^* s$ then there is a term $u$ such that $t \to_\beta^* u \to_\eta^* s$, and if moreover $s$ is $\beta\eta$-normal then $u$ is $\beta$-normal.
Indeed, from this property and its consequences, it follows that the $\beta$-normal form of $\lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_i.xt_1 \dots t_j$ is $\lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_i.xt_1' \dots t_j'$, where $t_1', \dots, t_j'$ are the $\beta$-normal forms of $t_1, \dots, t_{j}$, respectively.
Then the $\beta\eta$-normal form $s$ of $\lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_i.xt_1 \dots t_j$ is just the $\eta$-normal form of $\lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_i.xt_1' \dots t_j'$, that is, $s = \lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_{i-n}. x t_1'' \dots t_{j-n}''$ for some $0 \leq n \leq \min\{i,j\}$ where $t_{1}'', \dots, t_{j-n}''$ are the $\eta$-normal forms of $t_1', \dots, t_{j-n}'$, respectively.
Note that $n > 0$ if (and only if) $t_j = v_i$ and $v_i$ does not occur free in the term $x t_1 \dots t_{j-1}$ (this implies in particular $x \neq v_i$), because in that case $\lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_i.xt_1' \dots t_j' = \lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_{i-1}.\lambda v_i.xt_1' \dots t_{j-1}'v_i \to_\eta \lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_{i-1}.xt_1' \dots t_{j-1}' = s'$, and you can repeat the same argument with $v_{ i-1}, t_{j-1}$ in $s'$, and so on until you get $\lambda v_1 \dots \lambda v_{i-n}. x t_1' \dots t_{j-n}'$ whose $\eta$-redexes are only in $ t_1', \dots, t_{j-n}'$.
Therefore, either $x = v_k$ for some $1 \leq k \leq i$ and then $x$ does not occur free in $s$, or $x \neq v_k$ for all $1 \leq k \leq i$ and then $x$ still occurs free (in head position) in $s$.

A term of the shape $λv_1.\dots λv_i.x t_1 \dots t_j$ is called a head normal form. Such terms are particularly stable wrt. reductions, indeed:

A β-reduction step cannot change the head structure of the term, i.e. it can only produce a term of the shape $λv_1.\dots λv_i.x t'_1 \dots t'_j$.
The only η-contraction step modifying the head structure occurs in case $t_j = v_i$, namely
$$λv_1.\dots λv_i.x t_1 \dots t_{j-1}v_i \longrightarrow_η λv_1.\dots λv_{i-1}.x t_1 \dots t_{j-1}.$$

In both cases, the head variable $x$ is preserved, hence it remains free (provided $x$ is distinct from all the $v_i$, of course; otherwise it is already bound initially).
